# Adding an element to each permutation of a nested list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, nested-lists

Let's say I have a nested list

```
[1,2,3]
```

When I use the Data.List module to permutate this list, the result is the following:

```
> permutations [1,2,3]
=> [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[1,3,2]]
```

But I want it such that, I'm concatenating a 0 at the end of each tail. Example:

```
=> [[1,2,3,0],[2,1,3,0],[3,2,1,0],[2,3,1,0],[3,1,2,0],[1,3,2,0]]
```

I'm thinking that the only way of doing this is modifying the source code of permutations as a different function but I'm not sure how to incorporate the concatenation into it. This would be the source:

```
import Data.List

permutations            :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations xs0        =  xs0 : perms xs0 []
  where
    perms []     _  = []
    perms (t:ts) is = foldr interleave (perms ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
      where interleave    xs     r = let (_,zs) = interleave' id xs r in zs
            interleave' _ []     r = (ts, r)
            interleave' f (y:ys) r = let (us,zs) = interleave' (f . (y:)) ys r
                                     in  (y:us, f (t:y:us) : zs)
```

If there's a better way to approach this by using the permutation function without permutating the zero, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do this at the permutation level already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might be more efficient to do this at the permutation level, we can simply first do all the permutations, and then *post process* this, with a `map`, so:

```
import Data.List(permutations)

our_perm :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
our_perm = map (++[0]) . permutations
```

Comment: That's actually much more simpler than expected. Thanks!